# Why is the array empty on get allFiles with Laravel storage

Tags: laravel, ftp

I have an Laravel application witch works with an ftp server. Till now, I used the ftp service from hostpoint.ch. Everything works well.
Now, the customer like to use his own ftp server. So I created a new disk for the new ftp.

```
        'ftp_customer' => [
            'driver' => 'ftp',
            'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xx.x',
            'username' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'port' => 21,
            'passive' => true,
            'root'=> '/',
        ],
```

To test the server, I created the following script:

```
        Storage::disk('ftp_customer')->put('file1.txt', 'Contents');
        $files = Storage::disk('ftp_customer')->allFiles();

        dd($files);
```

On the server, the file1.txt exists:

`-rw-rw-rw- 1 ftp ftp               8 Dec 20 13:43 file1.txt`

Therefore, I know, that the `put` method works.

But the `get allFiles` returns always an empty array.

I tried to create first a folder and use it. Also, I tried to change the config.

I'm not sure if it creates problems, because it's a Windows server.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: @geertjanknapen I tried it allready

Comment: I deleted the comment since I tested in my own project and that seems to work. Did you `composer require league/flysystem-ftp "^3.0"` install this?

Comment: Hmmm... could you try to run `php artisan storage:link` ??

Comment: Finally, the moved the ftp server from the windows machine to a linux machine. And now it works. I don't know the reason....

Comment: @Peter Could have to do with certain permissions, I don't know the gist of it though, glad you got it fixed!